# How can I share one same function between two components far away

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have one function `funA` on component A, `ComponentA` and another component B, `componentB`. Now, I want to `ComponentB` to use this same function, `funA`.

How can I share this `funA` to `ComponentB`?

I was thinking about `redux`, but redux doesn't suggest passing a non-serializable value, like a function, to a state.

What's the solution for this?

Edit: the `funA` persisting some states of `componentA`, I want to keeping these states when using on `componentB`. I was trying to create a custom hook, however the hook is a individual closure for each time call the hook, which means I cannot hold the state.

Edit: I have created a custom hook, but it's not working, maybe I should include some codes.

On my custom hook:

```
const useActionsHook = () => {
  const [action, setAction] = useState([])
  const addAction = (actionNew) => {
    setAction(prev=>[...prev, actionNew])
  } 
  const getActions = () => {
    return action
  }
  return {
    getActions, addAction
  }
}
```

In ComponentA, I call `const {addAction} = useActionsHook` then save the action. And on ComponentB, I call `const {getActions} = useActionsHook` then to get actions, but that `getActions` value is still the empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Put the function in its own file and import it in both places:

```js
// fun-a.js
export function funA () {
  return "woo";
}
```

```js
// component-a.js
import { funA } from './fun-a.js';

export function ComponentA (props) {
  return (
    <div>{funA()}</div>
  );
}
```

```js
// component-b.js
import { funA } from './fun-a.js';

export function ComponentB (props) {
  return (
    <div>{funA()}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: no, my condition is more complex than this, I want to persist the state inside the function instead of simple pass the function itself.

Comment: If you want to persist the state, try `useContext` or create a custom hook

Answer (score 0):

Put this data from a ComponentA to redux store. If you need this data from store formatted by some function "funA", create selector:

```
export const funASelector(store) {
  // do something with data from store and return the result
}
```

Or if you don't have redux or don't want to use it, use react context to store data from ComponentA and provide this data to ComponentB. When you receive data at ComponentB, call the function to format data

Comment: but redux doesn't want you to save a function to state.

Comment: I don't said about saving function in redux. I said that you can save state of one component in redux and share this state with other components by selector function

Answer (score 0):

You can make it hook with logic you need and pass the data needed to hook within the component